# Extract height from DTM into attribute table of point layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4

I have an empty point layer (100 random points) and a dtm.

I was wondering how I would go about to get the height from the dtm underneath each point into the points attribute table?

Answer (score 0):

"Extract Values to Points" of the spatial analyst might the easiest way.
More information here:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-values-to-points.htm